# sqlalchemy polymorphic_identity in list

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following setup and was hoping I can have polymorphic inheritance where both `id_2` and `id_3` discriminator values would map the same Child model. In sqlalchemy, is it possible to designate `polymorphic_identity` with a list of possible values?

```
class Parent(ScoutModel):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    identifiers = ('id_1', 'id_2', 'id_2')

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    discriminator = Column(String(4), nullable=False, default=identifiers[0])

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': discriminator,
    }


class Child(Company):
    __tablename__ = 'child'

    id = Column(ForeignKey('parent.id'), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': '???',
    }
```

Is there another approach that could accomplish this perhaps?

Thank you,
Fydo